# Remove is not allowed error as described in var logs

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

Following error in  **var/log/system** file

or it is appearing in main site .

I have seen these files even in vendor also but issue is still there .

I have removed **var/cache , var/generated , var/view_preprocessed**

almost i did everything but issue is there .

[image]

Comment: Have you overrided cms_index_index?

Comment: no did nothing . but upgrade to 2.2.6 maybe it is issue because of upgrade

Answer (score 0):

As per your error screen, it seems you have added **remove** attribute in some container element.

**remove** is only allowed and works for blocks.